# Angular 6 - Call a field of B component from a tamplate of A component

Tags: angular

I need insert a Sum field of a Payment component to a template Invoice of an Invoice component. How can I do this? I need replace {{invoice.paymentId}} from Invoice template to a field Sum from Payment component.

PaymentModel

```
import { Moment } from 'moment';
import { Money } from 'app/shared/model/money.model';
import { Currency } from 'app/shared/model/currency.model';

export interface IPayment {
    id?: number;
    date?: Moment;
    invoiceId?: number;
    sum?: Money;
}

export class Payment implements IPayment {
    constructor(public id?: number, public date?: Moment, public invoiceId?: number, public sum?: Money) {
        this.sum = new Money(undefined, Currency.UAH);
    }
}
```

Payment Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { DATE_FORMAT } from 'app/shared/constants/input.constants';

import { SERVER_API_URL } from 'app/app.constants';
import { createRequestOption } from 'app/shared';
import { IPayment } from 'app/shared/model/payment.model';

type EntityResponseType = HttpResponse<IPayment>;
type EntityArrayResponseType = HttpResponse<IPayment[]>;

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PaymentService {
    private resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/payments';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    create(payment: IPayment): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
        const copy = this.convertDateFromClient(payment);
        return this.http
            .post<IPayment>(this.resourceUrl, copy, { observe: 'response' })
            .map((res: EntityResponseType) => this.convertDateFromServer(res));
    }

    update(payment: IPayment): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
        const copy = this.convertDateFromClient(payment);
        return this.http
            .put<IPayment>(this.resourceUrl, copy, { observe: 'response' })
            .map((res: EntityResponseType) => this.convertDateFromServer(res));
    }

    find(id: number): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
        return this.http
            .get<IPayment>(`${this.resourceUrl}/${id}`, { observe: 'response' })
            .map((res: EntityResponseType) => this.convertDateFromServer(res));
    }

    query(req?: any): Observable<EntityArrayResponseType> {
        const options = createRequestOption(req);
        return this.http
            .get<IPayment[]>(this.resourceUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response' })
            .map((res: EntityArrayResponseType) => this.convertDateArrayFromServer(res));
    }

    delete(id: number): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
        return this.http.delete<any>(`${this.resourceUrl}/${id}`, { observe: 'response' });
    }

    private convertDateFromClient(payment: IPayment): IPayment {
        const copy: IPayment = Object.assign({}, payment, {
            date: payment.date != null && payment.date.isValid() ? payment.date.format(DATE_FORMAT) : null
        });
        return copy;
    }

    private convertDateFromServer(res: EntityResponseType): EntityResponseType {
        res.body.date = res.body.date != null ? moment(res.body.date) : null;
        return res;
    }

    private convertDateArrayFromServer(res: EntityArrayResponseType): EntityArrayResponseType {
        res.body.forEach((payment: IPayment) => {
            payment.date = payment.date != null ? moment(payment.date) : null;
        });
        return res;
    }
}
```

Payment Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { JhiEventManager, JhiParseLinks, JhiAlertService } from 'ng-jhipster';

import { IPayment } from 'app/shared/model/payment.model';
import { Principal } from 'app/core';

import { ITEMS_PER_PAGE } from 'app/shared';
import { PaymentService } from './payment.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-payment',
    templateUrl: './payment.component.html'
})
export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    currentAccount: any;
    payments: IPayment[];
    error: any;
    success: any;
    eventSubscriber: Subscription;
    routeData: any;
    links: any;
    totalItems: any;
    queryCount: any;
    itemsPerPage: any;
    page: any;
    predicate: any;
    previousPage: any;
    reverse: any;

    constructor(
        private paymentService: PaymentService,
        private parseLinks: JhiParseLinks,
        private jhiAlertService: JhiAlertService,
        private principal: Principal,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private eventManager: JhiEventManager
    ) {
        this.itemsPerPage = ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
        this.routeData = this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
            this.page = data.pagingParams.page;
            this.previousPage = data.pagingParams.page;
            this.reverse = data.pagingParams.ascending;
            this.predicate = data.pagingParams.predicate;
        });
    }

    loadAll() {
        this.paymentService
            .query({
                page: this.page - 1,
                size: this.itemsPerPage,
                sort: this.sort()
            })
            .subscribe(
                (res: HttpResponse<IPayment[]>) => this.paginatePayments(res.body, res.headers),
                (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
            );
    }

    loadPage(page: number) {
        if (page !== this.previousPage) {
            this.previousPage = page;
            this.transition();
        }
    }

    transition() {
        this.router.navigate(['/payment'], {
            queryParams: {
                page: this.page,
                size: this.itemsPerPage,
                sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')
            }
        });
        this.loadAll();
    }

    clear() {
        this.page = 0;
        this.router.navigate([
            '/payment',
            {
                page: this.page,
                sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')
            }
        ]);
        this.loadAll();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadAll();
        this.principal.identity().then(account => {
            this.currentAccount = account;
        });
        this.registerChangeInPayments();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.eventManager.destroy(this.eventSubscriber);
    }

    trackId(index: number, item: IPayment) {
        return item.id;
    }

    registerChangeInPayments() {
        this.eventSubscriber = this.eventManager.subscribe('paymentListModification', response => this.loadAll());
    }

    sort() {
        const result = [this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')];
        if (this.predicate !== 'id') {
            result.push('id');
        }
        return result;
    }

    private paginatePayments(data: IPayment[], headers: HttpHeaders) {
        this.links = this.parseLinks.parse(headers.get('link'));
        this.totalItems = parseInt(headers.get('X-Total-Count'), 10);
        this.queryCount = this.totalItems;
        this.payments = data;
    }

    private onError(errorMessage: string) {
        this.jhiAlertService.error(errorMessage, null, null);
    }
}
```

Invoice Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { DATE_FORMAT } from 'app/shared/constants/input.constants';

import { SERVER_API_URL } from 'app/app.constants';
import { createRequestOption } from 'app/shared';
import { IInvoice } from 'app/shared/model/invoice.model';

type EntityResponseType = HttpResponse<IInvoice>;
type EntityArrayResponseType = HttpResponse<IInvoice[]>;

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class InvoiceService {
    private resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/invoices';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    create(invoice: IInvoice): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
        const copy = this.convertDateFromClient(invoice);
        return this.http
            .post<IInvoice>(this.resourceUrl, copy, { observe: 'response' })
            .map((res: EntityResponseType) => this.convertDateFromServer(res));
    }

    update(invoice: IInvoice): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
        const copy = this.convertDateFromClient(invoice);
        return this.http
            .put<IInvoice>(this.resourceUrl, copy, { observe: 'response' })
            .map((res: EntityResponseType) => this.convertDateFromServer(res));
    }

    find(id: number): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
        return this.http
            .get<IInvoice>(`${this.resourceUrl}/${id}`, { observe: 'response' })
            .map((res: EntityResponseType) => this.convertDateFromServer(res));
    }

    query(req?: any): Observable<EntityArrayResponseType> {
        const options = createRequestOption(req);
        return this.http
            .get<IInvoice[]>(this.resourceUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response' })
            .map((res: EntityArrayResponseType) => this.convertDateArrayFromServer(res));
    }

    delete(id: number): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
        return this.http.delete<any>(`${this.resourceUrl}/${id}`, { observe: 'response' });
    }

    private convertDateFromClient(invoice: IInvoice): IInvoice {
        const copy: IInvoice = Object.assign({}, invoice, {
            dateFrom: invoice.dateFrom != null && invoice.dateFrom.isValid() ? invoice.dateFrom.format(DATE_FORMAT) : null,
            dateTo: invoice.dateTo != null && invoice.dateTo.isValid() ? invoice.dateTo.format(DATE_FORMAT) : null
        });
        return copy;
    }

    private convertDateFromServer(res: EntityResponseType): EntityResponseType {
        res.body.dateFrom = res.body.dateFrom != null ? moment(res.body.dateFrom) : null;
        res.body.dateTo = res.body.dateTo != null ? moment(res.body.dateTo) : null;
        return res;
    }

    private convertDateArrayFromServer(res: EntityArrayResponseType): EntityArrayResponseType {
        res.body.forEach((invoice: IInvoice) => {
            invoice.dateFrom = invoice.dateFrom != null ? moment(invoice.dateFrom) : null;
            invoice.dateTo = invoice.dateTo != null ? moment(invoice.dateTo) : null;
        });
        return res;
    }
}
```

Invoice Module

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HipsterfoxSharedModule } from 'app/shared';
import {
    InvoiceComponent,
    InvoiceDetailComponent,
    InvoiceUpdateComponent,
    InvoiceDeletePopupComponent,
    InvoiceDeleteDialogComponent,
    invoiceRoute,
    invoicePopupRoute
} from './';

const ENTITY_STATES = [...invoiceRoute, ...invoicePopupRoute];

@NgModule({
    imports: [HipsterfoxSharedModule, RouterModule.forChild(ENTITY_STATES)],
    declarations: [
        InvoiceComponent,
        InvoiceDetailComponent,
        InvoiceUpdateComponent,
        InvoiceDeleteDialogComponent,
        InvoiceDeletePopupComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [InvoiceComponent, InvoiceUpdateComponent, InvoiceDeleteDialogComponent, InvoiceDeletePopupComponent],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class HipsterfoxInvoiceModule {}
```

Invoice Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { JhiEventManager, JhiParseLinks, JhiAlertService } from 'ng-jhipster';

import { IInvoice } from 'app/shared/model/invoice.model';
import { Principal } from 'app/core';

import { ITEMS_PER_PAGE } from 'app/shared';
import { InvoiceService } from './invoice.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-invoice',
    templateUrl: './invoice.component.html'
})
export class InvoiceComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    currentAccount: any;
    invoices: IInvoice[];
    error: any;
    success: any;
    eventSubscriber: Subscription;
    routeData: any;
    links: any;
    totalItems: any;
    queryCount: any;
    itemsPerPage: any;
    page: any;
    predicate: any;
    previousPage: any;
    reverse: any;

    constructor(
        private invoiceService: InvoiceService,
        private parseLinks: JhiParseLinks,
        private jhiAlertService: JhiAlertService,
        private principal: Principal,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private eventManager: JhiEventManager
    ) {
        this.itemsPerPage = ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
        this.routeData = this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
            this.page = data.pagingParams.page;
            this.previousPage = data.pagingParams.page;
            this.reverse = data.pagingParams.ascending;
            this.predicate = data.pagingParams.predicate;
        });
    }

    loadAll() {
        this.invoiceService
            .query({
                page: this.page - 1,
                size: this.itemsPerPage,
                sort: this.sort()
            })
            .subscribe(
                (res: HttpResponse<IInvoice[]>) => this.paginateInvoices(res.body, res.headers),
                (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
            );
    }

    loadPage(page: number) {
        if (page !== this.previousPage) {
            this.previousPage = page;
            this.transition();
        }
    }

    transition() {
        this.router.navigate(['/invoice'], {
            queryParams: {
                page: this.page,
                size: this.itemsPerPage,
                sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')
            }
        });
        this.loadAll();
    }

    clear() {
        this.page = 0;
        this.router.navigate([
            '/invoice',
            {
                page: this.page,
                sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')
            }
        ]);
        this.loadAll();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadAll();
        this.principal.identity().then(account => {
            this.currentAccount = account;
        });
        this.registerChangeInInvoices();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.eventManager.destroy(this.eventSubscriber);
    }

    trackId(index: number, item: IInvoice) {
        return item.id;
    }

    registerChangeInInvoices() {
        this.eventSubscriber = this.eventManager.subscribe('invoiceListModification', response => this.loadAll());
    }

    sort() {
        const result = [this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')];
        if (this.predicate !== 'id') {
            result.push('id');
        }
        return result;
    }

    private paginateInvoices(data: IInvoice[], headers: HttpHeaders) {
        this.links = this.parseLinks.parse(headers.get('link'));
        this.totalItems = parseInt(headers.get('X-Total-Count'), 10);
        this.queryCount = this.totalItems;
        this.invoices = data;
    }

    private onError(errorMessage: string) {
        this.jhiAlertService.error(errorMessage, null, null);
    }
}
```

Invoice template

```
<div>
    <h2 id="page-heading">
        <span jhiTranslate="hipsterfoxApp.invoice.home.title">Invoices</span>
    </h2>
    <jhi-alert></jhi-alert>
    <br/>
    <div class="table-responsive" *ngIf="invoices">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr jhiSort [(predicate)]="predicate" [(ascending)]="reverse" [callback]="transition.bind(this)">
            <th jhiSortBy="id"><span jhiTranslate="global.field.id">ID</span> <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon></th>
            <th jhiSortBy="contractId"><span jhiTranslate="hipsterfoxApp.invoice.contract">Contract</span> <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon></th>
            <th jhiSortBy="dateFrom"><span jhiTranslate="hipsterfoxApp.invoice.dateFrom">Date From</span> <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon></th>
            <th jhiSortBy="dateTo"><span jhiTranslate="hipsterfoxApp.invoice.dateTo">Date To</span> <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon></th>
            <th jhiSortBy="sumId"><span jhiTranslate="hipsterfoxApp.invoice.sum">Sum</span> <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon></th>
            <th jhiSortBy="paymentId"><span jhiTranslate="hipsterfoxApp.invoice.payment">Payment</span> <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon></th>
            <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let invoice of invoices ;trackBy: trackId">
                <td><a [routerLink]="['/invoice', invoice.id, 'view' ]">{{invoice.id}}</a></td>
                <td>
                    <div *ngIf="invoice.contractId">
                        <a [routerLink]="['../contract', invoice.contractId , 'view' ]" >{{invoice.contractId}}</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>{{invoice.dateFrom | date:'mediumDate'}}</td>
                <td>{{invoice.dateTo | date:'mediumDate'}}</td>
                <td>{{invoice.sum.amount + ' ' + invoice.sum.currency}}</td>
                <td>
                    <div *ngIf="invoice.paymentId">
                        <a [routerLink]="['../payment', invoice.paymentId, 'view']" >{{invoice.paymentId}}</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    <div class="btn-group flex-btn-group-container">
                        <button type="submit"
                                [routerLink]="['/invoice', invoice.id, 'view' ]"
                                class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                            <fa-icon [icon]="'eye'"></fa-icon>
                            <span class="d-none d-md-inline" jhiTranslate="entity.action.view">View</span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit"
                                [routerLink]="['/invoice', invoice.id, 'edit']"
                                class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                            <fa-icon [icon]="'pencil-alt'"></fa-icon>
                            <span class="d-none d-md-inline" jhiTranslate="entity.action.edit">Edit</span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit"
                                [routerLink]="['/', { outlets: { popup: 'invoice/'+ invoice.id + '/delete'} }]"
                                replaceUrl="true"
                                queryParamsHandling="merge"
                                class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                            <fa-icon [icon]="'times'"></fa-icon>
                            <span class="d-none d-md-inline" jhiTranslate="entity.action.delete">Delete</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="invoices && invoices.length">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <jhi-item-count [page]="page" [total]="queryCount" [maxSize]="5" [itemsPerPage]="itemsPerPage"></jhi-item-count>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="totalItems" [(page)]="page" [pageSize]="itemsPerPage" [maxSize]="5" [rotate]="true" [boundaryLinks]="true" (pageChange)="loadPage(page)"></ngb-pagination>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a PaymentService and a InvoiceService. I have the paymentId from the InvoiceComponent but I don't understand how to get the field Sum from Payment

Comment: Bad design flaw?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You should start by giving your whole model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this in a few ways

thing you can do is redesign flaw, you can create a component that contain the payment and contain the invoice, they will be shown be ngIf. after you did yhis you can get what you need from on component to anther with @Input and @Output 
you can read about it in [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

the second thing you can which is my recommendation, you can use Rxjs Subject
you will create an observable in the service and subscribe it in the component and just use the next() function to pass is to the invoice component 
you can read about it [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-subjects-5c585188c3e1)